# scale font lower than 0.01 is handled as 0.01

Tags: libgdx

Every value I set for `.scale()` lower than 0.01 will be handled as I set 0.01, rendering a text that is not lower than when I set it to 0.01.

```
FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter sizeParams = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
sizeParams.fontFileName = "MyFont.ttf";
sizeParams.fontParameters.size = (int)Math.ceil(2*MINIMUM_VIEWPORT_SIZE_PIXEL/9f/2f/2f);
sizeParams.fontParameters.color = new Color(Color.Red);
sizeParams.fontParameters.borderColor = new Color(Color.Green);
sizeParams.fontParameters.borderWidth = 2;
sizeParams.fontParameters.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
sizeParams.fontParameters.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
assetManager.load("MyFont.ttf", BitmapFont.class, sizeParams);
assetManager.finishLoading();

BitmapFont fontFreeType = assetManager.get("myFont.ttf", BitmapFont.class);

Label.LabelStyle miniLabelStyle = new Label.LabelStyle();
miniLabelStyle.font = fontFreeType;
miniLabelStyle.font.getData().scale(0.005f);

Label labelDebug = new Label("my sample text", game.miniLabelStyle);
```

I tried this, without any change (either setting `true` or `false`):

```
miniLabelStyle.font.setUseIntegerPositions(false);
```

I tried this, but the text results so grainy:

```
labelDebug.setFontScale(0.5f);
```

How to get a lower scale than 0.01?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, since I don't use FreetypeFontGenerator, but maybe what you're missing is mip mapping, which is necessary for drawing images smaller than their original size without them getting blurry and chunky.

You'll want to make these two settings to enable it, I think:

```
sizeParams.fontParameters.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear;
sizeParams.fontParameters.genMipMaps = true;
```

You might also need to add padding around the glyphs so characters don't absorb some of their neighbors when shrunk down. (Settings `padTop`, `padLeft`, `padBottom`, `padRight`.)

However, there's a reason mip mapping defaults to being disabled. Text looks clearest if it's generated at exactly the size it will be on screen and is rendered with nearest filtering. This isn't universally true, since you might be projecting your text in 3D space or scaling it up and down in real-time. But if it's static text for a GUI, it's probably best to calculate exactly what size it would need to be for it to be one-texture-pixel to one-screen-pixel.